# Generic polymorphism

Tags: vb.net

Please take a look at the code below:

```
    Public Class Student
    Public Sub PassList(ByVal StudentList As List(Of Student))
        Dim s1 As New Student
        Dim s2 As New Student
        Dim s3 As New Student
        StudentList.Add(s1)
        StudentList.Add(s2)
        StudentList.Add(s3)
    End Sub

    Public Sub TestReturnList()
        Dim list As List(Of PostGraduate)
        PassList(list)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class PostGraduate
    Inherits Student
End Class

Public Class PostUndergraduate
    Inherits Student
End Class
```

There is a compiler error:

> Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of WindowsApplication1.PostGraduate)' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of WindowsApplication1.Student)

I understand the reason for the error.  Is there a workaround?

Comment: "Is there a workaround?" - that depends on how the `StudentList` is *used* within `PassList`. If its only iterated over, then @Neolisk's answer is appropriate. If you're doing something else with it, you'd need to tell us what you're planning to *do* with the list in order for us to identify if a workaround is available.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I have added more to the question.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is a workaround. The caller (`TestReturnList`) has the very reasonable expectation, even after calling `PassList`, that if it iterates its `List(Of PostGraduate)`, the only things it find in there are `PostGraduate`s (or types derived from it). It would *not* expect to find plain `Student`s in this list.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about *variance*. Try changing this:

```
Public Sub PassList(ByVal StudentList As List(Of Student))

End Sub
```

to this:

```
Public Sub PassList(ByVal StudentList As IEnumerable(Of Student))

End Sub
```

*Variance* for generic type parameters is a new feature in .NET 4.0.

Read more about [Covariance and Contravariance here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx).

Comment: unfortunately this won't work for me (I have added more to the question).  Thanks.

Comment: @w0051977: Change this `Dim list As List(Of PostGraduate)` to this `Dim list As List(Of Student)`. No, it will not prevent you from adding `PostGraduate` students to it.

Comment: PassList should be able to accept PostGraduates or undergraduates.  A list will contain either all undergrauates or all postgraduates.

Comment: @w0051977: That's exactly what I said above. It will be able to accept both, and even at the same time, if declared as `Dim list As List(Of Student)`.